# How to use @Input without binding property in parent component

Tags: angular, input, data-binding

I have 2 component table and optIn
table component has button which opens optIn component
table ts file

```
openModal(){
    const dialogRef =  this.dialog.open(OptInComponent);
}
```

table html

```
<button (click)="openModal()"></button>
```

I have @Input which is used in table component like

```
<table [getData]="Data"></table>
```

and this is used in table ts file as

```
@Input getData
```

But how can i pass same @Input in optIn Component?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass it as a property :-

```
dialogRef.getData = this.Data;
```

Comment: Do i still need to use @Input getData in optIn component?

Comment: nope you don't need it